# pass QGLFrameBufferObject to ShaderEffectItem as Image

Tags: opengl, buffer, shader, qml

How can I bind QGLFrameBufferObject as an Image for the ShaderEffectItem in QML? QML documentation does not contain any examples of how to pass the processed image in qml script.

Answer (score 1):

You don't. You bind the textures that you *put into* the FBO as an image. Assuming those weren't renderbuffers, of course.